# Why is of two same types of xmls, one is not deserializing and the other is?

Tags: c#-2.0, xml-deserialization

Suppose I have two different xml files as embedded-resource in a same assembly:

**Hummer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<car company="GMC" brand="Hummer" />
```

**HammerHead.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shark species="HammerHead" length="45" />
```

**Car.cs**
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
namespace XmlDeserialization_Test
{
    [XmlRoot("car"), XmlType("car")]    
    public class Car
    {
        [XmlAttribute("company")]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("brand")]
        public string Brand { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Shark.cs**
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
namespace XmlDeserialization_Test
{
    [XmlRoot("shark"), XmlType("shark")]
    public class Shark
    {
        [XmlAttribute("species")]
        public string Species { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("length")]
        public double Length { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlDeserialization_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
            List<Shark> sharkList = new List<Shark>();

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("XmlDeserialization_Test.exe");
            string[] manifestResourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

            Array.Sort<string>(manifestResourceNames);

            foreach (string mrn in manifestResourceNames)
            {
                Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(mrn);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shark));
                object obj = serializer.Deserialize(stream);

                if (obj is Car)
                {
                    carList.Add((Car)obj);
                }
                else if (obj is Shark)
                {
                    sharkList.Add((Shark)obj);
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

HammerHead - Shark is deserializing perfectly.

But, Hummer - car is not. The following exception is being generated:

```
There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
"<car xmlns=''> was not expected."
```

If Shark is deserializing, why Car is not? If Car is generating exception, why Shark is not?

I am clueless!!!

Comment: From the error, it looks like the XML in your resource is not the same as what you posted here.  It is complaining about content that isn't in the document that you posted.

Comment: Which xml Hummer or HammerHead?

Comment: Hummer.  Look- it is complaining about the following content: <car xmlns=''>.  That isn't in the XML document that you posted.

Comment: Why doesn't same go with HammerHead?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying the desearilize a 'car' object with a 'shark' deserialize it. If you change to create a deserializer of type Car, you'll have the opposite result:

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(**Car**));

I don't know how you're serializing, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But how to solve that while achieving the desired result? I am not serializing. Just trying to deserialize from two different xml text files.

Comment: Just deserialize sharks with an `XmlSerializer(typeof(Shark))` and
 deserialize car with an `XmlSerializer(typeof(Car))`.

Comment: If you know the resource name, you can check the value of "mrn" and build the proper desiarilizer based on that.